# Use reference template arguments in inner class

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code:

```
template<class V, class Ref = V&>
class Util {
public:
    typedef Ref reference;
};

template<class D, class V, class Ref = V&>
class Base {
public:
    class Inner1: public Util<const V, const Ref> {
    public:
        Inner1(const D &d) :
                d(d) {
        }
        typename Inner1::reference foo() const {
            static V v;
            return v;
        }
    private:
        const D &d;
    };
    class Inner2: public Util<V, Ref> {
    public:
        Inner2(D &d) :
                d(d) {
        }
        typename Inner2::reference foo() const {
            static V v;
            return v;
        }
    private:
        D &d;
    };
};

class Child: public Base<Child, float> {
public:
    Inner1 getInner1() const {
        return Base<Child, float>::Inner1(*this);
    }
    Inner2 getInner2() {
        return Base<Child, float>::Inner2(*this);
    }
};

void print(float & ff) {

}

int main() {
    Child c;
    Child::Inner1 inner = c.getInner1();
    print(inner.foo());
    return 0;
}
```

This code compile without problems but I guess I should receive a compilation error. The method foo of class `Inner1` should return a `const` reference, but for unknown reason `Ref` is defined without `const`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but for unknown reason Ref is defined without const. Why?

Leading const is misleading. In the type `Util<const V, const Ref>` you `const` qualify the `Ref` type. I.e., you supposedly pass `V & const` as the type, and not `V const &`. While normally `V & const` would be ill-formed, when dealing with the type indirectly, such as when it's aliased or a template argument, the extra cv-qualifier is simply ignored.

Personally, I would use the extra template parameter for an entire trait.

```
template<class V>
class VTrait {
public:
    typedef V & reference;
    typedef V const & const_reference;
};

template<class D, class V, class Trait = VTrait<V>>
class Base {
public:
    class Inner1: public Util<const V, typename Trait::const_reference> {
     // ...
    };

  // ...
};
```

Client code that wants something different from your framework will need only customize the `Trait`.

Comment: I just adapted my code to have a minimal example, however Util is boost::iterator_facade so I can't modify it

Comment: @greywolf82 - Then create your own trait. Use that one in `Base` (which I presume is yours) instead of the extra argument. Feed its `const_reference` member to `boost::iterator_facade`.

Answer (score 1):

`const Ref`, given `Ref` is `V&`, i.e. `float&`, note that `const` is qualified on the reference itself, not the type being referenced. The `const` qualifier is just omitted, you're still getting `V&`, but not `const V&` as you expected. (To be precise there's no *`const` references* in C++ but only *references to `const`* or *to non-`const`*.)

If you change `const Ref` to `const V&` (i.e. reference to `const`), you'll get the error you expected. e.g.

```
class Inner1: public Util<const V, const V&> {
    ...
```